# change project name and package name

Tags: android

Is it possible to change the project name and package name in Android.

Comment: It is possible, as answers below tell you.

I just have to add that if you've published your app to Android Market, you will have to do it all over.
Meaning you'll loose all your current users, possibly having to maintain two instances of the app on Android Market simultaneously while you notify users of the change - as the package name isn't the same anymore. 

So think it through before you decide to change.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You change it in the [manifest file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html). That is where you can change a whole bunch of settings about the android project itself.

Comment: Thanks, I can change the package from the manifest. But what about the visible project name? The android project name. Thanks

Comment: Okay do you mean the project name that appears in you IDE (Eclipse?) or the one that appears when you put the app on your phone/tablet?

Comment: The project name that appears in the IDE, the project explorer. But it doesn't matter now as I got the application to work in another project. Thanks

Comment: @Deqing actually he doesn't mention how to change the package name and strings.xml. Check **ritesh4326**'s answer instead and the comments :P

Answer (score 26):

Project Name:

```
res -> values -> strings.xml -> app_name -> (change the name)
```

Package name:

Right click on the project -> Android tools -> Rename application package -> (change the name)

Answer (score 18):

**Change Package Name :**

1. Right Click on Project >Android Tools >Rename Application Package
2. Go to src right click on your main package >Refactor >Rename
3. Go to manifest file and change your package name .

   **Change Project Name :**
4. Right click on Project Refactor >Rename

Comment: Thank you, this is the only reply that almost fully answers the question... The 5th step is to update the __values\strings.xml__ `app_name` line (as others mentioned) and if you support multiple languages, update also __values-[language]\strings.xml__.

Comment: However, there's one thing I noticed that I haven't been able to change. When I click the down arrow near the __Run Icon__ the old name of the project is still there... Any guess?

Comment: Sorry if this is a noob question. Where is the 'Project' which I should right click?

Answer (score 11):

Try this

1. Right click on your project.
2. Click "Refactor"
3. Click "Rename..."
4. List item

Enter name!

Or did that not work for you?

Comment: When I tried this today it didn't work with "Can't rename root module"

Comment: it is not going to work if you want to rename root module ; so goto manifest.xml file and change the name

Answer (score 6):

```
1. Right click on project in project pane.
2. Click "Open module settings"
3. In the project structure frame, click app below the Modules
4. Click "Flavors" and change "Application Id".
5. Edit Manifest.xml in your project and rebuild it.
```

Comment: 0. Open project pane (upper left) 
1.  Right click on App in project pane.  Continue via step 2

Answer (score 5):

If you want to change the name of your application as it shows on the phone just change the value in the app_name variable. The Path is res -> values -> strings.xml -> app_name

[image]

Comment: Actually I find this to be the most accurate answer.

Answer (score 3):

I just finish modifying the package name and I hope this will help. I am using eclipse.

First you should have a backup of your `AndroidManifest.xml`, then you can select `Refactor -> Rename` to the package you want to change the name.

My eclipse Refactor will change the `AndroidManifest.xml` and make it not even able to compile, so I just paste the `AndroidManifest.xml` I backup, and change the package name by myself to the new one.

By the way, you should clean your project first, so the file auto generated in the `gen` folder will be cleaned.

When you build again with your new `AndroidManifest.xml`, you will get the correct `gen` folder.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

If You're trying to change the root module name and getting **"Can't rename root module"** error , open the **gradle.settings** file and change the **rootProject.name** to whatever you want then **sync** .[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

for edit name of app follow steps....

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on package name in one of your java class or activity, then reactor it and write your own package name then click ok.
2. Open the manifest and change your package name according to your package name in java class

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of Project in file -> (settings.gradle)

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the `android:label` attribute of the `application` tag in the manifest? If so, you could set it directly like so:

```
    <application
        ...
        android:label="My title"
        ... >
```

Or configure the string resource this points to by default, I think it was called `app_name`. Open the file `strings.xml` in the project subfolder `res/values/` and edit it there.

Answer (score 0):

The project name is defined in the file **.project** as below. It is at the same level of your AndroidManifest.xml. I experienced it when I wanted to add to my workspace a project with the same projectName of an existing one and could find where it was defined. The Manifest file does not help in such case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
<name>YourProjectName</name>
<comment></comment>
<projects>
</projects>
<buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
<natures>
    <nature>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
</natures>
```

Answer (score 0):

For change your package name of any application.

Try this

1 . Right Click on project name go to android tools then rename application package
 enter new package name then click ok and update according to it.

2.Go to your main package name then right click then refactor and rename enter new package     name.

3.Go to manifest and change old package with the new package name.

Now you can run your project.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add a little to [Robert Massaioli's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5137323/1065835)

If you have custom attributes used in your XML files ([Creating a View Class](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html)), you'll also have to rename your XML namespaces.

`xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.myold"`

must be renamed to

`xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mynew"`

Answer (score 0):

1) Close Android Studio

2) Copy Old Project and rename it to the new one

3) Reopen android studio and import the new project

4) Go to the old package name and rename it according to your new project

5) Them, Click on Edit ==> Find ==> Replace in Path and replace old occurrences of your old project name to the new one

6) Clean the project and rebuild again

Thats it

Answer (score 0):

In this Sample I want to change My Application Title to Surah Al Baqrah with Translation.

Change your view to Android. Go to App --> Res --> Values --> Strings.xml
You can update the code below:

```
<string name="app_name">My Application</string>
```

which will look like:

[image]

to:

```
    <resources>
        <string name="app_name">Surah Al Baqrah with Translation</string>
    </resources>
```

which will look like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Hope this will help someone.